# class method with static and not-static overloads

Tags: python

I have a Python class `MyClass` with a method `do_something`. I would like this method to have an optional parameter `some_param`. So far the code looks like this:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, some_param)
        self.some_param = some_param

    def do_something(some_param=None):
        if some_param:
            pass
        else:
            some_param = self.some_param

    @staticmethod
    def do_something_static(some_param):
        pass
```

is it possible to have the `do_something_static` and `do_something` have the same name?

In other words:

if `some_param` is provided I would like `do_something` to be a static method.

If `some_param` is not provided, then it would not be a static method since it needs to access `self.some_param`.

`MyClass` needs to have both functionalities and I'd like to have them in a single function, callable both as a static method and as a non-static one: is it possible?

---

why? I'd rather not have different functions doing the same thing. `do_something_static` really sounds like "I didn't know how to do it any better". What I'm asking is if it possible to access `self` in a static method, given that I won't do that if it is called with the needed parameter that replaces `self`.

Comment: Not really, Python doesn't support polymorphism/method overloading based on signature.

Comment: *"is if it possible to access self in a static method"* - no, if you have access to `self` it isn't static. You can only have one method with a given name (unless you do some manual multi-dispatch, e.g. with a decorator, like `@property`, and even then I suspect you'd have issues trying to combine static and instance methods).

Comment: I understand, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to have a function that, if it's called as a method will take it's argument from an attribute of `self`, but otherwise just uses its single argument directly. You can do this in Python 3, where unbound methods are plain old functions (but not in Python 2, where unbound methods require their first argument be an instance).

Here's a quick example:

```
class MyClass:
    def func(arg):
        if isinstance(arg, MyClass):
            # if we were called as arg.func(), get the actual arg value from an attribute
            arg = arg.some_attribute

        # do something with arg
        print(arg)

# MyClass.func can be called like a static method
MyClass.func("foo")

# or as a method of an instance of MyClass
instance = MyClass()
instance.some_attribute = "bar"
instance.func()
```

Now, I suppose this won't do what you want if the argument you pass to the static method might be an instance of the class (which the code above will mis-recognize as calling the method on the instance). I don't think there's a good way around that that wouldn't require a lot of work with descriptors.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a normal function:

```
def do_something(some_param):
    # do the work
    pass
```

and use it in the class:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, some_param)
        self.some_param = some_param

    def do_something(some_param=None):
        if some_param:
            do_something(some_param)
        else:
            do_something(self.some_param)
```

The implementation would be only inside the function but you can use it in the method. Seems to be simplest approach that avoids duplication of functionality.

Comment: although I found the other answer to be more canonically useful, I've sticked with this approach since I'm not allowed to use Python 3. Thank you!